# How do I match only the content of function string arguments?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I'm importing the `classnames` library as `cx`, and using it to generate Tailwind class name strings in a React project like this.

```
  const buttonClasses = cx(
    'flex flex-row items-center',
    'text-wave-brown text-xl p-1.5 rounded-xl',
    selected && 'bg-slate-800',
    isDisabled && 'text-zinc-700 bg-transparent',
    props.className
  );
```

The Tailwind Intellisense plugin supports adding a regex to trigger autocomplete. I've added the bottom row (`"cx\\(([^\\)]*)\\)"`) in the VS Code config.

```json
  "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
    "tw`([^`]*)", // tw`...`
    "tw=\"([^\"]*)", // <div tw="..." />
    "tw={\"([^\"}]*)", // <div tw={"..."} />
    "tw\\.\\w+`([^`]*)", // tw.xxx`...`
    "tw\\(.*?\\)`([^`]*)", // tw(Component)`...`


    "cx\\(([^\\)]*)\\)" // cx(...)
  ],
```

This works, but it triggers autocomplete even outside of the string literals. I would prefer to only get autocomplete when my cursor is inside of a string literal (between the `'` ticks).

**Is there a way to write the regex so that it only matches the content inside the string literals that are also arguments of the `cx()` function?**

Comment: how do you know that the `'` is the string starting quote

Comment: Is there only one string argument per line?  That is a pretty important consideration.  And can `)` occur anywhere before the end of the `cx()` function?

Comment: @rioV8 for me single quote strings are what I use. Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: @Mark good questions! First answer is that there could be more than one string argument per line. Second is a good observation, I actually don’t care much about the ending parens, and technically there could be a function call in the arguments list.

Comment: If the regex seas a `'` how do determine it is the start of a string and not the end

Comment: @rioV8 That's part of the scope of the question. `'([^']*)'` will match everything between two `'`. But I need to know how to repeat that inside of another match.

Comment: From what I see, it looks like they have some notion of `container`/`context` in the `classRegex` completions. Can you have a look at https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7553#issuecomment-735915659 and see if it's what you're after?

Comment: @qaziqarta Sorry for late reply, but yes. This is exactly what I needed to solve my problem. Would you like to write it into an answer and I'll accept it as the solution?